# Using Microsoft Publisher to draw high quality flowcharts?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

Plenty of journals and magazines require high quality images when you get to submit a paper.

I`m trying to get a simple flow chart of mine into a higher quality version.

Is MS Publisher enough to do so ? I do not have any other "Corel Draw like" software .

What you think ?

Comment: Flow chart? I guess LibreOffice Draw is just fine. Easy to use and you can easily connect lines. You could save the picture in .eps format if you are using LaTeX. This should give a very quality outlook.

Comment: @Abdulhameed, what if I also need to add some figures to the flow chart? does Draw work just fine ? 
I`m gonna have a look at this. cheers!

Comment: Yes you can import figures and cliparts to LibreOffice

Comment: In professional texts, put space only after the marks, and never before.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I used the Publisher and it worked just fine. It was a quite simple task.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any software and later improve the quality of your chart with a vector software like Inkscape (or actually, you can draw the flowchart directly there). I could recommend you using Draw.io (https://www.draw.io/). It performs quite well, you can save your flowcharts directly to the cloud, and you can export your flowcharts in SVG format.